# How to tile a background on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, gnome-shell, desktop-background

I am running 18.04 (new laptop for work) and I do not see an option to tile, stretch or fit the background image for the desktop. How do I do this?

When I go to the Background Pane of Settings, I don't see an option
[image]

Nor do I see an option when I select a custom image to tile
[image]

Searching for "tile" does not show anything either
[image]